# component has been registered but not used vue/no-unused-components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Created my component `EmployeeTable.vue`
Then I exported as

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "employee-table"
};
</script>
```

But when I import it in `App.vue` as follows `import EmployeeTable from "@/components/EmployeeTable.vue";`
I get this error

```
error  The "EmployeeTable" component has been registered but not used  vue/no-unused-components
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's your es-lint setup. You can change it to not that strict rules or you can fix this actual problem.
1. Make sure that in `App.vue` you registered it in a components section like this:

```
...
components: {
    EmployeeTable
},
...
```

2. Make sure you used it in `App.vue` template:

```
<EmployeeTable />
```

Comment: is there a way to omit this error if it is not directly in your template? I am trying to create the components dynamically so I only want them inserted into my dom when necessary and not at all times

Comment: To change to NON-STRICT, see answer below by another user.

Comment: @DanielvanDommele my answer might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65046057/67022

Answer (score 12):

use Component instead of component

```
Components: {
    EmployeeTable
},
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: This works, but for me it also triggers a bunch of Vue warnings in the console.

Answer (score 7):

## Avoid the error the right way

I'm assuming that OP ran into this situation for the same reason I did: App includes ComponentA, which includes ComponentB. But we're mistakenly including ComponentB in App.vue even though it's not directly used there. (I didn't realize at first that the imports and components list was supposed to be in each component rather than at the toplevel .vue file.)

The way to avoid the error in that case is for ComponentA.vue to have:

```
import ComponentB from './ComponentB.vue'

export default {
    name: 'ComponentA',
    components: {
        ComponentB
    },

...

}
```

Note: do not include ComponentB in App.vue. It isn't referenced directly here and that is what the linter is warning you about.

## Turn off the warning (last resort)

If you're hitting this warning for some other reason, and you really need to turn it off in the linter, edit package.json. Find the section for `"eslintConfig": {...}` and make sure it includes `"rules": {"vue/no-unused-components": "off"}`.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to disable component registered state. Use this code

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable vue/no-unused-components */
export default {
  name: "employee-table"
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

For importing other resources like js files or potentially some animation files or anything that can't be added or called in the HTML/Template section, you can set your eslint rules in the package.json

```js
 "rules": {
    "strict": "off"
  }
```

Comment: The correct config for this should be: { "vue/no-unused-components": "off"}

Answer (score 1):

The name of the component is sensitive to uppercase and lowercase letters, such as write below ...

```
  import EmployeeTable from './components/EmployeeTable.vue'
  export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  EmployeeTable,
   }
```

And on the template,We write similarly to the name we have defined...

```
<template>
<div> 
<EmployeeTable />
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import component remove .vue

Example :

```
        <template>
      <div id="app">
        <Header />
        <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
        <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';
    import Header from './components/Header/Header';

    export default {
      name: 'App',
      components: {
        HelloWorld,
        Header,
      }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
    #app {
      font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      text-align: center;
      color: #2c3e50;
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have faced this befor , make sure you write the name of component correctly without missing or adding any letter , i hope every thing works then

Answer (score -3):

1. First of all I recommend that you use phpstorm to ensure all the relevant files are imported.
2. Then secondly in the App.vue register the EmployeeTable in the component section like this ...

   components: {
   HelloWorld
   }

...
3. Most importantly make use of

````
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld></HelloWorld>
  </div>
</template>```

in the App.vue
````